# Laravel does not load

Tags: php, apache, laravel

Everything went well, I've run `laravel new`, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName laravel.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/blog/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/blog>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then

```
a2ensite laravel.example.com
```

And reloaded apache and add `"127.0.0.1  laravel.example.com" >> /etc/hosts`

Now when I go to http://laravel.example.com the source code of [index.php](http://pasted.co/eb7b865a) is printed

Comment: maybe your php is not enabled.

Comment: Looks like you have a php error in your configuration, what php version are you on?

Comment: Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: I did a php reinstall, now PHP is loaded, phpinfo() works, but now it's just white page, so Laravel is not starting somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A white page may be cause by many problems. Try to `chmod -R 0777` storage folder, maybe Laravel does not have the permissions to write in that folder and will not even be able to show the error page. Or you may check your apache error logs

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the "DirectoryIndex" in your virtualhost file? It seems that it's not defined.